# Nativescript - Use Enter key to submit a prompt dialog

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I can't figure out how to make the keyboard enter key press the ok button or run a function. When I display a prompt dialog, the enter key hides the keyboard on ios and/or makes another line on android. It should press the ok button instead.

Any help appreciated

Thanks Jacklin

```
var dialogsModule = require("ui/dialogs");

dialogsModule.prompt({
    message: "Add new activity:",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    okButtonText: "Add"
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newest question with response [How do I change the return key type of a text from a prompt in NativeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888508/how-do-i-change-the-return-key-type-of-a-text-from-a-prompt-in-nativescript)

This is still the first result in Google for certain keywords so I'm pasting here the answer but it's not good news:

> Unfortunately you can not do that. As of today {N} do not expose the
>   underlaying native view for dialogs so it's not possible to override
>   natively.
>
> You will have to build the complete custom dialog yourself to achieve
>   what you are looking for.