# How do I change the return key type of a text from a prompt in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, prompt, angular2-nativescript

Changing the return key type of TextViews/TextFields is pretty straight forward, however, since prompts don't use any html there's no obvious way to change the return key type. the NativeScript docs don't indicate there being any way to change it either.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not do that, {N} do not expose the underlaying native view so it's not possible to override natively. You will have to build the complete custom dialog yourself to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: OK thank you for the response

Comment: Can you make this an answer not a comment so I can mark this question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not do that. As of today {N} do not expose the underlaying native view for dialogs so it's not possible to override natively.

You will have to build the complete custom dialog yourself to achieve what you are looking for.